# Evaluate $\int x \arcsin(x)dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate:
> $$\int x \arcsin(x)dx$$

My first guess was $u$ substitution but that didn't get me very far. I think using integration by parts is the correct way. Here's my attempt:

$$u = \arcsin(x), v' = x \Longrightarrow \int x \arcsin(x)dx = \arcsin(x) \cdot \frac{x^2}{2} - \int \frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

But I am stuck on how to continue from here.

Comment: In your last integral, integrate by parts by differentiating x and integrating the other stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track. As regards the remaining integral, note that
$$\int \frac{x^2}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1-(1-x^2)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx
=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx-\frac{1}{2}\int \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx.$$
The first integral is easy, whereas for the second one you may use the substitution $x=\sin(t)$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: The first integral would then become $\frac{1}{2} \arcsin(x)$ and for the second integral you would have to use $u-$substitution and the solution to it would be $\frac{\arcsin(x)+x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{4}$. Combining the solutions would then give me the solution for the original integral.

Comment: @SkiMask Exactly. Well done!

Comment: Using $x=\sin t$ at the start would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate by parts twice

\begin{align}
\int x \arcsin x\> dx &=\frac12 x^2 \arcsin x -\frac12 
\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx\\
&=\frac12 x^2 \arcsin x+\frac14
\int \frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \>d\left( 1-x^2\right)\\
 &=\frac12 x^2 \arcsin x +\frac14 x \sqrt{1-x^2} - 
\frac14\arcsin x+ C\\
\end{align}